# Escape characters in MySQL, in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, special-characters

I have a couple escaped characters in user-entered fields that I can't figure out.

I know they are the "smart" single and double quotes, but I don't know how to search for them in mysql.

The characters in ruby, when output from Ruby look like \222, \223, \224 etc

```
irb> "\222".length => 1
```

So - do you know how to search for these in mysql?  When I look in mysql, they look like '?'.

I'd like to find all records that have this character in the text field.  I tried

```
mysql> select id from table where field LIKE '%\222%'
```

but that did not work.

Some more information - after doing a mysqldump, this is how one of the characters is represented - '\\xE2\\x80\\x99'.  It's the smart single quote.

Ultimately, I'm building an RTF file and the characters are coming out completely wrong, so I'm trying to replace them with 'dumb' quotes for now.  I was able to do a gsub(/\222\, "'").

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your problem but here is some info for you:

- First, there are no escaped characters in the database. Because every character being stored as is, with no escaping.
- they don't "look ilke `?`". I's just wrong terminal settings.  SET NAMES query always should be executed first, to match client encoding.
- you have to determine character set and use it on every stage - in the database, in the mysql client, in ruby.
- you should distinguish ruby strings representation from character itself.
- To enter character in the mysql query, you can use [char function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char). But in terminal only. In ruby just use the character itself.
- smart quotes looks like 2-byte encoded in the unicode. You have to determine your encoding first.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out, this was caused by a the mysqldump and subsequent source > db/backups/file.sql.  The characters in the original database looked OK and I was able to do the regular expression check as usual.  I just didn't imagine the dump and import would do that.